View Model Variables Becomes Null When called in the View
When I try to call the variable qrImage from my view it gets a null value while from the view model the variable is not null since it has gotten a new value. I confirmed this by logging the qrImage Variable from both the View and View Model.
Here is my View Model. The QR image is Generated.
@HiltViewModel
class CreateQrViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val qrUseCases: QrUseCases
) : ViewModel() {


    //private val _qrState = MutableStateFlow(CreateQrState())
    //val qrState = _qrState.asStateFlow()

    var qrName by mutableStateOf("")
    var qrUrl by mutableStateOf("")
    val qrImage = mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null)

    fun createQrCode() {
        Log.i("QR Code Name: ", qrName)
        Log.i("QR Code URL: ", qrUrl)
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // Run on IO thread
            try {
                val createdDate = Calendar.getInstance()
                val qrModel = QrModel(qrName = qrName, qrUrl = qrUrl, createdDate = createdDate)
                qrUseCases.addQrUseCase(qrModel)

                val qrData = "${qrModel.qrName} - ${qrModel.qrUrl}"
                val generatedImage = QRCodeGenerator.generateQRCode(qrData)

                qrImage.value = generatedImage

                //_qrState.value = CreateQrState(qrName = qrName, qrUrl = qrUrl, qrImage = generatedImage)
                Log.i("QR CODE: ", qrImage.toString())
                //_qrImage.value?.let { saveImage(it) }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("Creating QR code failed:", "Failed", e)
            }
        }
    }

CreateQrScreen View - Where the function create QrCode Is Called
Button(
                onClick =
                {
                    viewModel.createQrCode()
                    Log.i("QR CODE IMAGE", viewModel.qrImage.toString())
                    navController.navigate(route = NavigationRoutes.Download.route)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(80.dp)
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text("Create QR Code")
            }

This is my view. From the View It Logs QR CODE IS NULL.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DownloadQrScreen(
    navigateUp: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: CreateQrViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    //val qrState = viewModel.qrState.collectAsState().value

    val qrImage = viewModel.qrImage.value

    if(qrImage == null)
    {
        Log.i("QR CODE IS NULL", viewModel.qrImage.value.toString())
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("QR CODE", "QR CODE IS NOT Null")
    }

I tried using the mutable state flow to get all the data from the view model.
I also did use the mutable state with the same but still null on my view.

Where do you call createQrCode then?

Please provide a [mre] that we can use to reproduce the problem for ourselves.

in another View. There is a button that calls that function. Here it is
Button(                 onClick =                 {                     viewModel.createQrCode()                     Log.i("QR CODE IMAGE", viewModel.qrImage.toString())                     navController.navigate(route = NavigationRoutes.Download.route)                 },

Are you sure that you have the same instance of your viewModel in both views then? Log viewModel.hashCode() in both views and see if it's the same

They are different Hash Codes. Would that be the problem? If so what do you suggest I do?

Yes, that is the problem. You have to use jetpack navigation (or similar solution) and scope the viewModel to navigation graph. See this sample in which InnerRouteA
and InnerRouteB share the same instance of ParentViewModel: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:hilt/hilt-navigation-compose/samples/src/main/java/androidx/hilt/navigation/compose/samples/HiltViewModelSamples.kt;drc=e5c41ae7a8917ccfcc69fe5bc94fce8eef491454;l=46
